Move Certain Lines To the Top of the List
Please can someone help me with the the regular expression for the following.
I would like to move lines which has the word blue to the top of the list.
Paul has a red BMW i7
Tina has black Mercedes A-Class
Robert has a silver Volkswagen Golf
Michelle has a blue Audi S7 Sportback
Carl has a white Tesla Model Y
Bradley has a blue Ford Edge

What I want:
Michelle has a blue Audi S7 Sportback
Bradley has a blue Ford Edge
Paul has a red BMW i7
Tina has black Mercedes A-Class
Robert has a Silver Volkswagen Golf
Carl has a white Tesla Model Y

Thank you


Ctrl+H
Find what: \A([\s\S]+?)^(.+blue.+\R)
Replace with: $2$1
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

You have to click Replace all as many times as needed to move all the lines that contain blue
Explanation:
\A              # beginning of file
  (               # group 1
    [\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  )               # end group
^               # beginning of line
  (               # group 2
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    blue            # literally
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
  )               # end group

Replacement:

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):

